# How to iterate or deal with grid or coordinate in python

Tags: python, grid, coordinates

I have created a forest with random number in a grid of N x N. For creating the forest, I have taken each grid and a random number to plant a tree. And store the planted coordinate in a list `li[]` for x-axis and `lj[]` for y-axis. And also put the coordinate in a .dat file

In python, here is my code:

```
from math import *
from random import random

n = input('Choose grid, N = ')
p = 0.5

li = []
lj = []

fid = open('plant.dat','w')
for i in range(1,n+1):
    for j in range(1,n+1):
        x = random()
        if x<p:
            li.append(i)
            lj.append(j)

            print>>fid,i,j
            print (i,j),'is',1
        else:
            print (i,j),'is',0
        print (i,j)
        print (p,x,n),'and',n*n*p,li,lj
```

Now I want to fire it. I start with the bottom points and set them on fire. And from there the fire spread in the all four direction to the adjacent points in the forest. Not in diagonal direction.

for that I check where y-axis is 1, it is the bottom point, in the list `lj[]` and put that point as fired.

Now I have to spread the fire to the adjacent tree (not in the diagonal) direction:

Here I'm stucked and don't know how to do this. Basically I want to follow the fired point in the bottom line and increase the value of x-axis and y-axis and check its adjacent point.
But it shows only the bottom line.

Here is my code :

```
print 'Now we are firing'
lif=[]
ljf=[]
fid1 = open('fire.dat','w')
for b in range(len(lj)):
    if lj[b] == 1:
        print 'We fire here',(li[b],lj[b])
        print>>fid1,li[b],lj[b]
        lif.append(li[b])
        ljf.append(lj[b])
        #for e in range(2,n+1):
        for r in li:
            if li[r] == li:
                print 'fire spread at',(li[r],lj[r])
                print >> fid1,li[r],lj[r]
                lif.append(li[r])
                ljf.append(lj[r])
```

here is my plot for 'plant.dat' file , by gnuplot:
[image]

In the above picture , clearly fire can go up to a certain extend and stop, leaving many living trees.

I want the coordinate of that living trees only and plot it.

For the particular input plot shown above, the final plot with the remaining living trees should look like as follows:

[image]

The partially erased points are fired and shouldn't be there.

Comment: Sorry, but what exactly is your question? What is the problem with the code you have? Errors (provide full traceback)? Unexpected outputs (provide inputs and expected and actual outputs)?

Comment: @jonrsharpe in the above code i want the output point which will plot my second image. From my above code, it does not show any error mesage, but the plot from the file 'fire'dat' does not look like this.

Comment: What do you mean "output point"? Can't you just plot the grid after the "fire" however you plot it before?

Comment: @jonrsharpe the output point here I mean the coordinate like (1,3) which has not been fired and are living...    I have plot the first one from the date file 'plant.dat' in the gnuplot

Comment: How does that relate to gnuplot? You must get your algorithm right.

Answer (score 2):

This is a good example of when recursive functions can make a difficult problem relatively easy. But first I want to represent your problem in a numpy matrix instead of index vectors while keeping most of your code intact. Here is your second code snippet where I represent the entire forest with 0.5 representing trees and 1 representing fires.

```
print 'Now we are firing'
lif=[]
ljf=[]
fid1 = open('fire.dat','w')
for b in range(len(lj)):
    if lj[b] == 1:
        print 'We fire here',(li[b],lj[b])
        print>>fid1,li[b],lj[b]
        lif.append(li[b])
        ljf.append(lj[b])

import numpy as np
forest_mat = np.zeros([n,n])
coords = zip(li,lj)
for coord in coords:
    forest_mat[coord[0]-1,coord[1]-1] = 0.5

coords = zip(lif,ljf)
for coord in coords:
    forest_mat[coord[0]-1,coord[1]-1] = 1

forest_mat = np.flipud(forest_mat.transpose())
```

Now I will define a function fire_trees which recursively fires adjacent trees by setting their values to 1. We do this for every tree in the first row since those were previously set aflame.

```
def fire_trees(matrix,ij):
    if ((0 <= ij[0]) and (ij[0] < len(matrix)) and (0 <= ij[1]) and (ij[1] < len(matrix)))==False:
        print "out of bounds"
        return matrix

    if matrix[ij[0],ij[1]]==0.5:

        print "Fire this tree:", ij[0],ij[1]
        matrix[ij[0],ij[1]] = 1

        matrix = fire_trees(matrix,(ij[0]-1,ij[1]))
        matrix = fire_trees(matrix,(ij[0]+1,ij[1]))
        matrix = fire_trees(matrix,(ij[0],ij[1]-1))
        matrix = fire_trees(matrix,(ij[0],ij[1]+1))

    print "No more trees to fire."
    return matrix

for i,j in enumerate(forest_mat[n-1,]):
    if j==1:
        #fire adjacent trees
        forest_mat = fire_trees(forest_mat,(n-2,i))
```

Instead of using gnuplot, I used matplotlib's matshow function as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
image = forest_mat
row_labels = range(n)
plt.matshow(image)
plt.show()
```

[image: forest]

Comment: `plt.matshow()` nice! Wish I'd known about that a long time ago.